# Let $G = S_3$. Show that the normalizer of $\{1,(123),(132)\}$ is all of $S_3$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

> The normalizer of $H$ under the action of $G$ is
>   $$N_G(H) = \{g ∈ G | gHg^{−1} = H\}$$
>
> $S_3=\{(),(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(1,2,3),(1,3,2)\}$
>
> Let $G = S_3.$ Show that the normalizer of $\{1,(123),(132)\}$ is all of $S_3.$

First of all I guess $1$ and () are equal, it is just a notational difference(if it's not let me know)

Now I wanna ask how I should proceed to get all those elements in $S_3.$

I started as:

For $1\in H, g1g^{-1}=1 \in H  ,\forall g\in G$

For $(123)\in H, 1(123)1^{-1}=(123) \in H $

For $(123)\in H, (12)(123)(12)^{-1}=(132) \in H$

For $(123)\in H, (13)(123)(13)^{-1}=(132) \in H$

For $(123)\in H, (23)(123)(23)^{-1}=(132) \in H$

For $(123)\in H, (123)(123)(123)^{-1}= (123) \in H$

For $(123)\in H, (132)(123)(132)^{-1}=(123)\in H$

I suppose I will get similar results for $(132)\in H \qquad$ 
as well. After showing that too am I done ? Are my computations valid? Or is there any better solution?

Also I wanna ask that is it true that $(12)^{-1}=(12) , (13)^{-1}=(13), (23)^{-1}=(23), (123)^{-1}=(123), (132)^{-1}=(132) $

I did this way on the above calculations

Comment: Compare with homework solution for $4$ [here](http://palmer.wellesley.edu/~ivolic/pdf/Classes/MATH306AlgebraTopicsSpring13/Solutions/306%20Topics%20in%20Alg.%20HW%202%20solutions.pdf). All transpositions have order $2$, so $(12)^{-1}=(12)$ etc.

Comment: The index of this subgroup is 2, thus will be normal subgroup.

Comment: There says it is straightforward which is not for me @DietrichBurde

Comment: You forgot to say that it says "We have to conjugating this set by the elements of $S_3$ and show that the result is always the same set." Indeed, then we are done.

Comment: That statement is not clear either. I mean the part "conjugating the set by the elts of $S_3$"

Comment: I mean yes we are conjugating but how are we sure that we get all the elements of $S(3)$ by conjugation, without showing it? It is not really clear to me that there is actually no need for those kinds of computations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you did is one way but there are a lot more ways.

From the definition, if H is a subgroup of G, then the largest subgroup in which H is normal is the subgroup $N_G(H)$. If $H$ is itself normal in $G$ then $N_G(H) = G$. This way if you check (for finite group) that the order of $\frac{G}{H}$ is the smallest prime dividing $G$ then $H$ is normal in $G$. So $N_G(H) = G$.

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes, thanks for the great explanations and answers you give to my questions @shrinit

Comment: @LeylaAlkan You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

First, since $H$ is a subgroup, the conjugate of $H$ by an element of $H$ just gives you $H$ again because $H$ is closed under multiplication.

Now all you have to deal with is conjugation of the $3$ elements in $H$ by the the $3$ elements not in $H$.

Conjugation of $1 =() \in H$ always gives $1$ again in any group.
That leaves only two elements of $H, (123)$ and $(132)$ which are inverses of one another.

Finally, if $(12)(123)(12) = (132)$ then $(12)(132)(12) = (123)$ because $(12)$ has order $2$. And similarly for $(13)$ and $(23)$.

That leaves you with just three conjugations to do, but you have already done them:

1. $(12)(123)(12)$
2. $(13)(123)(13)$
3. $(23)(123)(23)$

[BTW one of the conjugations listed in your question (not these) is mistaken.]

Comment: Which one is that? @StephenMeskin BTW, you made it a lot easier, thanks a lot!

Comment: I guess it is $(123)(123)(123)^{-1}=1 $

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: But isn't $(123)^{-1}=(123) $ as well?

Comment: No it isn't. If it were then $(123)(123)$ would $=1$ but it $=(132)$

Comment: So, by your saying, I guess when we take inverse of an element we actually swap the order as if there is a mirror: I mean $(123)^{-1}=(321)=(132)$ is this how it is done right? @StephenMeskin

Comment: Yes. That is one way of doing it.

Comment: You only have to check one additional element not in $H$. Because $H \leq N_{G}(H) \leq G$, we have by Lagrange's theorem that $|N_{G}(H)| \in \{ 3, 6\}$. So if you can show $N_{G}(H) \neq H$, then $N_{G}(H) = G$.

Comment: @ml0105 Yes, there are many solutions. See the other answers for example. The goal of this answer was to meet the student where she was, with the tools she had, and then push her a little.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one more way. Make the following two observations: the order of an element is equal to the order of any of its conjugates, and your subgroup contains *all* of the elements of orders 1 and 3 in $S_3$.

Comment: Expanding on John McHugh's answer, note that the action of conjugation preserves cycle type (which is a very useful fact). So conjugating $H = \langle (123) \rangle$ sends $H$ to another subgroup of $\text{Sym}(3)$ generated by a single $3$-cycle. As there is only one such subgroup in $\text{Sym}(3)$, you are done.